# how to forecast next time step using machine learning algorithm such as random forest

Tags: python, time-series, random-forest, forecast

I want to know how to forecast the next time step using a machine learning algorithm such as random forest, xgboost etc
lets say you have sales data up to 10th April, and you are doing daily forecasting, how do you obtain the sales for 11th April using these algorithms

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a sales record for each day. So, you need to form a vector of day numbers:

```
days = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., N]
```

Here `N` corresponds to the total number of sales records that you have and `0` corresponds to the first day in your data. Then you have a vector of sales records:

```
sales = [5, 7, 10, 12, 8, ..., 17]
```

Here `17` corresponds to the sales record on the `N`th day. So you build a model, using your favorite library (I'll use `scikit-learn`):

```
model = sklean.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor()
model.fit(days, sales)
```

Now with your trained model, you can predict any value. So, let's say you want to predict sales on the `N+1` day (and let's imagine that `(N+1)=50`).

```
prediction = model.predict(50)
```

Voila.

Comment: how about if its multivariate, how would the 'model.fit(time, sales)', be like?

Comment: you'll need to format the data to be a `numpy` array of size `(numberSamples, numberFeatures)`. So you'll have a feature array called `X` and the output data `sales`. Once formatted, the fit call is the same: `model.fit(X, sales)`.

Comment: @mark would you mind accepting this answer if it worked for you?

Comment: @CopyOfA how does it work if you have temperature timeseries with other factors? and want to predict next 50 years

Comment: @SHAH it works similarly. You'll have a `numpy` array of shape `(numberSamples, numberFeatures)` called `X` and a `numpy` vector of temperature values called `temperature`. Make the same call: `model.fit(X, temperature)`. Then you can call prediction in much the same way. The tricky bit with timeseries is that you'll need to tie each row of `X` and each entry of `temperature` to a time index (I assume you have equal sampling time). Then you `predict(N)`, where `N` is the number of time indices ahead for which you need to predict.